# google app engine (spring boot) local testing with data store gives Unauthenticated error

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

Google flexible app engine spring boot project running on local with datastore is giving the `com.google.cloud.datastore.DatastoreException` `Unauthenticated` exception while saving entity.

```
{
   "timestamp": 1512077140003,
   "status": 500,
   "error": "Internal Server Error",
   "exception": "com.google.cloud.datastore.DatastoreException",
   "message": "Unauthenticated.",
   "path": "/users"
}
```

The error description [here](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/errors) says the request header does not have valid authentication header, But where to place the auth header does not mentioned.

anybody faced same kind of situation?

Answer (score 8):

**Canonical Error Code:** `UNAUTHENTICATED`

**Description:** The `com.google.cloud.datastore.DatastoreException` simply indicates that the request did not have valid authentication credentials.

**Recommended Action:** Do not retry without fixing the problem. In this case, you need to check the login credentials again.

More read can be found on this page https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/errors#error_codes

**Solution:**

Simply you have to run `gcloud beta auth application-default login`.
But I spent a half of a day until found it [there](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication).
I thought it should be enough to `gcloud init`. As an alternative, you can use google authentication via Google OAuth2 but that is the hard way.

Comment: After running this command, I'm getting a different error now: `com.google.datastore.v1.client.DatastoreException: Permission denied on resource project no_app_id., code=PERMISSION_DENIED`. When I do `gcloud init` I can see that my project id is set. Any idea how to set the project id correctly when testing on local?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up going in another direction.

1. You can authenticate and use a remote Datastore, like [Amar mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48650606/1332865);
2. You can also get credentials, store it locally, reference it in your `application.properties` using the `spring.cloud.gcp.datastore.credentials.location=file://FULL_PATH_TO_THE_CREDENTIALS_FILE` and still use a remote Datastore;
3. But my favorite option is to run it full local using a Datastore emulator, so no authentication is needed at all:

### `src/test/resources/application.properties`

```
    # if it exists, comment out or delete the following property:
    # spring.cloud.gcp.datastore.credentials.location

    # add the following
    spring.cloud.gcp.emulator-enabled=true

    # if you're not using environment variables, make sure the following property exists
    spring.cloud.gcp.project-id=your-project-id
```

Be aware that if your running integration tests, or mixing remote and local tests, you might need different `.properties` files for each test.

### Your test class

```
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MethodHandles.lookup().lookupClass());

    private static LocalDatastoreHelper helper;

    @BeforeClass
    public static void setUpClass() throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        logger.info("[Datastore-Emulator] start");
        helper = LocalDatastoreHelper.create();
        helper.start();
        logger.info("[Datastore-Emulator] listening on port {}", helper.getPort());

        System.setProperty(DatastoreHelper.LOCAL_HOST_ENV_VAR, "localhost:" + helper.getPort());
    }

    @AfterClass
    public static void cleanUpClass() throws InterruptedException, TimeoutException, IOException {
        logger.info("[Datastore-Emulator] stop");
        helper.stop();
    }

    @Before
    public void init() throws IOException {
        logger.info("[Datastore-Emulator] cleaning data");
        helper.reset();
    }
```

This approach works great for Repositories (`org.springframework.cloud.gcp.data.datastore.repository.DatastoreRepository`), but if you want to use a `Datastore` directly, you can [check this](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/tools/localunittesting).

### Refs

- https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-java/blob/master/TESTING.md#testing-code-that-uses-datastore
- https://stackoverrun.com/ja/q/11110804