# com.google.cloud.datastore.DatastoreException: Unauthenticated. objectify java

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore, objectify

I have set up objectify v6 and when I try to save an entity I get this exception

> com.google.cloud.datastore.DatastoreException: Unauthenticated.
>
> Caused by: 
>   com.google.datastore.v1.client.DatastoreException: Unauthenticated., code=UNAUTHENTICATED

NOTE: I am only trying to save this entity on localhost.

Here is my code to save entity using objectify:

```
        Subscriber subscriber = new Subscriber(phone);
        ofy().save().entity(subscriber).now();
```

Comment: Your request did not have valid authentication credentials. Check [this SO question's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47583059/google-app-engine-spring-boot-local-testing-with-data-store-gives-unauthentica?rq=1)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. it did well solve my problem.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1102449/how-to-browse-local-java-app-engine-datastore/53919322#53919322