# Request had insufficient authentication scope [500]

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore

I have simple user class doing a create and update in Datastore. It's running fine locally, but when I deploy it on Kubernetes, it provides me with the below response:

`{
    "timestamp": 1525833559351,
    "status": 500,
    "error": "Internal Server Error",
    "exception": "com.google.cloud.datastore.DatastoreException",
    "message": "Request had insufficient authentication scopes.",
    "path": "/api/test/sample/5629499534213120"
}`

For reference, I have followed **[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47583059/google-app-engine-spring-boot-local-testing-with-data-store-gives-unauthentica)** Stack Overflow link.

Comment: Please check this [1] accepted answer which I believe is related to your issue. 

[1] https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35928534/403-request-had-insufficient-authentication-scopes-during-gcloud-container-clu?answertab=votes#tab-top

Comment: You might find these answers helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47021469/how-to-set-google-application-credentials-on-gke-running-through-kubernetes   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50275116/google-cloud-insufficient-authentication-scopes

Comment: I got the answer,Its because the service account i used while creating kubernative cluster .I used the correct one with the total access.Its working now.Thanks alot for help.

Comment: +ankush-nakaskar you could provide an answer to this question and get some extra points!