# How to set up an environment variables on google kubernetes engine?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

I am using `Firebase` in my `GoLang` project hosted on `Google Kubernetes Engine`.

Steps I followed:

1. Enable firebase admin SDK on the firebase account. It generated a service account `JSON` for me. This also created a service account under my Google console service credentials.
2. Followed this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50297314/834239) and add a new secret key using `kubectl create secret generic google-application-credentials --from-file=./sample-project.json`
3. Made changes to my `deployment.YAML` file (added volume mounts, and environment variable in)

   ```
   spec:
     containers:
     - image: gcr.io/sample-ee458/city:0.27
     name: city-app
     volumeMounts:
     - name: google-application-credentials-volume
       mountPath: /etc/gcp
       readOnly: true 
   env:
   - name: GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS
     value: /etc/gcp/application-credentials.json
   ```
4. setup volume in the same file

   ```
   volumes:
   - name: google-application-credentials-volume
   secret:
     secretName: google-application-credentials
     items:
     - key: application-credentials.json # default name created by the create secret from-file command
     path: application-credentials.json
   ```
5. Run `kubectl apply -f deployment.yaml` and deploy using `docker push` command.

It's throwing me `error getting credentials using google_application_credentials environment variable gke`. What am I missing here? Anny hint would be appreciable.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Finally, I figure out how to copy it and use the environment variable. Here is. the updated `YAML`file

```
apiVersion: apps/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: my-app
spec:
  template:
    spec:
      volumes:
      - name: google-cloud-keys
        secret:
          secretName: gac-keys
      containers:
      - name: my-app
        image: us.gcr.io/my-app
        volumeMounts:
        - name: google-cloud-keys
          mountPath: /var/secrets/google
          readOnly: true
        env:
        - name: GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS
          value: /var/secrets/google/new-file-name.json
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a Secret in two different ways:

- Mount the Secret as a **volume** and access it as a file
- Map the Secret to **environment variables** and access it by reading the variable

You seem to have mixed them both. Decide if you want to access it as a file (recommended) or as an environment variable.

See examples of both in the documentation:

- [Using Secrets as files from a Pod](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/secret/#using-secrets-as-files-from-a-pod)
- [Using Secrets as environment variables](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/secret/#using-secrets-as-environment-variables)

### Example - accessing it as an environment variable

First, create the Secret, this can be done as you did:

```
kubectl create secret generic google-application-credentials --from-file=./application-credentials.json
```

> I want to access it as an environment variable.

To expose the secret as an environment variable in the Pod or Deployment, write your Pod template as:

```
  containers:
  - name: city-app
    image: gcr.io/sample-ee458/city:0.27
    env:
      - name: GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS
        valueFrom:
          secretKeyRef:
            name: google-application-credentials  # name of the Secret
            key: application-credentials.json
```

When accessing the Secret as an environment variable, you don't need to add it as a volume.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I want to access it as an environment variable. Does that mean
`kubectl create secret generic....` command will create a secret key in `GKE`.  Where and how. should I map the `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` with json file?

Comment: Ah! Understand. BTW what is `application-credentials.json` here? Are you referring to `sample-project.json`?

Comment: Yeah,  you have mixed names there too. I updated so my `kubectl create secret` and the Pod-yaml has the same file name now.

Comment: Something is wrong: After applying the above configuration I am getting this:
`google: error getting credentials using GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS environment variable: open  open {\n  \"type\": \"service_account\",\n  \"project_id\": ....: file name too long"}* Closing connection 0`

It is pickinng up the file content instead of entire file using name.

Comment: Yes, that is how it works when you access the content through an environment variable

Comment: Yes, In my case I have to provide a file path in an environment variable but before doing it I have to copy a file to that path using YAML file. Correct?  Because the environment variable is expecting a file name or path not the file content

Answer (score 2):

The current answer is correct about secret, env vars and volumes. However, if you try to load authentication in GKE, I absolutely don't recommend to use Service account key file.

On GKE, there is a powerful feature named [workload identity](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/workload-identity). It act exactly as [metadata server on a compute engine instance](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/storing-retrieving-metadata) (and other product) but at pod and namespace level (create a proxy that intercept the metadata server call and redirect them to the correct credential, configured with workload identity).

It's more secure and you don't have to keep and manage secret file, with all the constraints and the risk that involve.